Difference TPU vs TPUQuic
I was testing some RPC api and invoking getClusterNodes I get this result:
    featureSet: 3746964731,
    gossip: '165.140.87.218:10000',
    pubkey: '2xte5CBkCBEBLNviyAfvSaTkMy6tvg99Cy3XJj9EJJs2',
    pubsub: null,
    rpc: null,
    shredVersion: 50093,
    tpu: '165.140.87.218:10003',
    tpuQuic: '165.140.87.218:10009',
    version: '1.17.31'

I wondering what's the difference between tpu and tpuQuic field.
I think it's the endpoint for UDP connections but I read that UDP connection aren't used anymore in Solana to send transaction, every client should use only QUIC protocol.
Could be that some validator has still UDP enabled but I always see the tpu entry populated so I don't think it's the case.

You've understood everything correctly. The tpu field is a legacy return value for the non-QUIC UDP transaction packets.
Even though it isn't used, it's still advertised for backwards compatibility purposes, or maybe it'll eventually be reused!
